# Sum of digits of a power

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Are there any explicit formula for a sum of digits for a power in the given base? A problem to be specific: find a sum of digits for a number $2^{100}$ in the system with a base 5. In the system with a base 10?

Comment: What do you mean by "explicit formula"?

Comment: There is an explicit formula for the digit sum of $a^b\bmod c$ if $a^b<10c$.

Answer (score 2):

The $b^k$'s digit of the base $b$ expansion of $x$ is $\lfloor x/b^k \rfloor \mod b$ (where I'm using "mod" as a function rather than a relation).  I doubt that you'll get anything much more "explicit" than $\sum_{k \ge 0} \left(\lfloor x/b^k \rfloor \mod b\right)$.